# Restrict miners in a private network

Tags: go-ethereum, miner

I am creating a private network of more than one nodes using geth client. I want that only few clients can get the access to mine blocks.May be i will provide a list of addresses of authorized miners. How can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: A mixture of PoA and PoS, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

With Parity, you can create your network with a list of authorized validators. See the following documentation for more details: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Pluggable-Consensus

Comment: I want to implement it using Geth.